# How can I make a grid area always be 100% width of the page?

Tags: css

I am building a simple calendar. The seven days should always occupy 100% of the screen together (it's ok if they individually schrink or expand to fit different screen sizes).

I thought it'd be as easy as setting the parent div to 100%, but shi hasn't worked.

This is what my HTML looks like

```
                     <div className="weeks">

                        <div className="week1">
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>
                            <div className="dayDiv">
                                </div>    
                        </div>

                     </div>
...
```

And this is what my CSS looks like.

```
.week1 {
        grid-template-areas: "x . . . . . .";
        width: 100%;
    }

.dayDiv {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: please can you show your rendered html and css in a [mcve]

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

```
.week1 {
        grid-template-areas: "x . . . . . .";
        width: auto;
    }

try this
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/flag-try-this-code-answers-as-very-low-quality to see a community discussion about "Try this" answers.